# Multiple Selection in Alert Dialog

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-dialog, android-sdk-2.3

Good Day,

I created a method showDialog which will show an Alert Dialog and will list multiple data that I can select of. My problem is when I click OK, the next  method (myMethod()) i want to call is not being called. Can someone help me with this? Here is my code:

```
private void showDialog(List<String> list) {
    final CharSequence[] dialogList=  list.toArray(new CharSequence[list.size()]);
    final AlertDialog.Builder builderDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SharingActivity.this);
    builderDialog.setTitle("Select Item");
    int count = dialogList.length;
    boolean[] is_checked = new boolean[count];
    String result = "";

    builderDialog.setMultiChoiceItems(dialogList, is_checked,
            new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton, boolean isChecked) {
                }
            });

    builderDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    ListView list = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
                    // make selected item in the comma seprated string
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.getCount(); i++) {
                        boolean checked = list.isItemChecked(i);

                        if (checked) {
                            if (stringBuilder.length() > 0) stringBuilder.append(",");
                            stringBuilder.append(list.getItemAtPosition(i));

                        }
                    }

                    myMethod(stringBuilder.toString()); //this is the method

                }
            });

    builderDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Click here to open Dialog");
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builderDialog.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Here is myMethod:

```
private void myMethod(String stringFriend){
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("image");

Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
//Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
        .setBitmap(image)
        .setCaption("")
        .build();
List<String> peopleIds =  new ArrayList<String>();
peopleIds.add(stringFriend);

SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
        .addPhoto(photo)
        .setPeopleIds(peopleIds)
        .build();

ShareApi.share(content, null);
```

}

Comment: How are you determining that `myMethod()` isn't being called? Have you put a log print here? A break point? Are you stepping through the code?

Comment: the process inside that method is not executing at all. But the weird thing is when I use the debug mode, and use stepping through, the myMethod is executing.

Comment: Are you sure that `myMethod()` just isn't executing as you expect?

Comment: Yes. I added the method. It is only executing when I try to debug and put breakpoints and step through. but in normal running, its not executing.

Comment: Put log prints in that method to determine what's failing during normal runtime. You might also test the method with a hard-coded `String`, without the `Dialog`.

Comment: I tried put logs. but it really doesnt go trough that method.. It will only get through during debug mode.